# how can I execute the call to function doing ajax request using jQuery $("#").click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a function that gets the form values and send them Flask backend to retrieve info from SQLite database. I'm using jQuery `$.ajax()` with `POST` to allow for better error handling.

Because the ajax is `async` I'm passing a callback to `logTable(callback)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/7582937). I need the `logTable()` to run after I input the form data and click the submit button. I'm using `$("#some-id").click()` to achieve this.

```js
      const logsTable = (callback) => {
        const startDate = $("#start-date").val();
        const endDate = $("#end-date").val();
        const container = $("#programs").val();

        const server = window.location.host;
        const url = `http://${server}/api/log-info`;
        let logs = "";

        let dataToSend = {
          start_date: startDate,
          end_date: endDate,
          program: container,
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: dataToSend,
          success: (data) => {
            callback(data);
          },
          error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
            alert(errorThrown);
          },
        });
      };

      $("#submit-button").click(() => {
        return logsTable((data) => {
          $("#logs-div").html(data);
          alert("Success");
        });
      });
```

I receive the alert with `Success`, the data briefly appears on the page and disappears. If run the code below directly it, it runs on page reload and posts an empty list to a page because no data was sent to the backend.

```js
logsTable((data) => {
  $("#logs-div").html(data);
  alert("Success");
});
```

I need to somehow the function call above to a `Submit` button. How can I do that?

Comment: The button with the id "submit-button" is probably an `input type="submit"` or a `button` or `button type="submit"`? Your form is being submitted to the server, which reloads the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)

Comment: @HereticMonkey it actuallt has no type at all `<button id="submit-button">Submit</button>`

Comment: That was one of the choices :). `button`'s default `type` is `submit`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yeah, after looking at the link, I added the `type=button` and now it's working, thank you.